# Отрисовка картинки в OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

Итак есть картинка, загруженная с помощью Devil, и кучка черных квадратов.

1) Картинка почему-то показывается перевернутой, как сделать ее прямой?

2) Когда я отрисовываю черные кубики, я ставлю цвет так:

```
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

И при перерисовке получается, что текстура заполняется черным цветом. Как я могу отменить действие этой функции, чтобы перерисовать текстуру?

код:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <chipmunk/chipmunk.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <IL/ilut.h>
#include "Object.h"

const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 500;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 500;
const int NUMBER_OF_CUBICKS = 100;
const int NUMBER_CUBICKS_BY_X = 20;
const int STEP_BY_Y = 20;
const int STEP_BY_X = 20;
const int START_POSITION_X = 50;
const int START_POSITION_Y = 370;

typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
  struct {
    uint32_t LowPart;
    long int HighPart;
  } ;
  struct {
    uint32_t LowPart;
    long int HighPart;
  } u;
  long long int QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER, *PLARGE_INTEGER;

cpSpace *space;
cpVect cell_vertices[ 4 ] = { cpv( -CUBICK_WIDTH / 2.0f, CUBICK_HEIGHT / 2.0f ), cpv( CUBICK_WIDTH / 2.0f, CUBICK_HEIGHT / 2.0f ),  cpv( CUBICK_WIDTH / 2.0f, -CUBICK_HEIGHT / 2.0f ), cpv( -CUBICK_WIDTH / 2.0f, -CUBICK_HEIGHT / 2.0f ) };
cpVect ground_vertices[ 4 ] = { cpv( -GROUND_WIDTH / 2.0f, GROUND_HEIGHT / 2.0f ), cpv( GROUND_WIDTH / 2.0f, GROUND_HEIGHT / 2.0f ), cpv( GROUND_WIDTH / 2.0f, -GROUND_HEIGHT / 2.0f ), cpv( -GROUND_WIDTH / 2.0f, -GROUND_HEIGHT / 2.0f ) };
cpVect trian[ 4 ] = { cpv( -110 / 2.0f, SCREEN_HEIGHT-260 / 2.0f ),  cpv( 130 / 2.0f, SCREEN_HEIGHT-280 / 2.0f ), cpv( 110 / 2.0f, -SCREEN_HEIGHT-280 / 2.0f )};
bool start = false;

LARGE_INTEGER old_tacts, current_tacts, freq;
FILE* performance_file;
char seconds_buff[ 100 ];
int times = 0;

void DevilInit(){
    if ( ilGetInteger ( IL_VERSION_NUM ) < IL_VERSION )
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Incorrect devil.dll version\n" );
    }

    if ( iluGetInteger ( ILU_VERSION_NUM ) < ILU_VERSION )
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Incorrect ilu.dll version\n" );
    }

    if ( ilutGetInteger ( ILUT_VERSION_NUM ) < ILUT_VERSION )
    {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Incorrect ilut.dll version\n" );
    }

    ilInit   ();
    iluInit  ();
    ilutInit ();
    ilutRenderer ( ILUT_OPENGL );
    ilSetInteger ( IL_KEEP_DXTC_DATA, IL_TRUE );
    ilutEnable   ( ILUT_GL_AUTODETECT_TEXTURE_TARGET );
    ilutEnable   ( ILUT_OPENGL_CONV );
    ilutEnable   ( ILUT_GL_USE_S3TC );
}

void CreateGround()
{
    cpShape* ground_shape = cpPolyShapeNew( &space -> staticBody, 4, ground_vertices, cpv( 250.0f, 50.0f ) );
    ground_shape -> e = 0.5f;  
    ground_shape -> u = 0.5f;
    ground_shape -> data = new Object( Ground );
    cpSpaceAddShape( space, ground_shape );

    /*cpShape* triangle = cpPolyShapeNew( &space->staticBody, 4, trian, cpv( 250.0f, 50.0f ) );
    triangle->e = 0.5f;
    triangle->u = 0.5f;
    triangle->data = new Object(Ground);
    cpSpaceAddShape( space, triangle );*/
}

void CreateCubicks()
{
    cpBody *cell_body = NULL;
    cpShape* cell_shape = NULL;

    for ( int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_CUBICKS; i++ )
    {
        cell_body = cpBodyNew( 250.0f, cpMomentForPoly( 100.0f, 4, cell_vertices, cpv(0.0f, 0.0f) ) );
        cell_body -> p = cpv( START_POSITION_X + STEP_BY_X * ( i % NUMBER_CUBICKS_BY_X ), START_POSITION_Y - STEP_BY_Y * ( i / NUMBER_CUBICKS_BY_X ) );
        cell_body -> a = (float)(rand() % 361) / 360.0f * 2 * pi;
        cell_body -> data = new Object( Cubick );
        cell_shape = cpPolyShapeNew( cell_body, 4, cell_vertices, cpv( 0.0f, 0.0f ) );
        cell_shape -> e = 0.5f; 
        cell_shape -> u = 0.5f;
        cpSpaceAddBody( space, cell_body ); 
        cpSpaceAddShape( space, cell_shape );
    }
}

void RenderScene()
{
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    cpArray *bodies = space -> bodies;
    cpBody *body = NULL;

    ILuint texID;
    GLuint id;
    ilGenImages(1, &texID);
    ilBindImage(texID);
    ilLoadImage("www.jpg");
    ilConvertImage(IL_RGB, IL_UNSIGNED_BYTE);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    //glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    //glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_SRC_COLOR);
    //glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    //glLoadIdentity();
    //glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    //glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //glClearDepth(0.0f);
    glGenTextures(1, &id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, id);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_BPP), ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_WIDTH),
            ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_HEIGHT), 0, ilGetInteger(IL_IMAGE_FORMAT), GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
            ilGetData());
    ilDeleteImages(1, &texID);
    /* Draw a quad */
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(256, 256);
        glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(256, 0);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0,   0);
        glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0,   256);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glDeleteTextures(1, &id);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    glBegin( GL_QUADS );

        glVertex3f( 250 + ground_vertices[ 0 ].x, 50 + ground_vertices[ 0 ].y, 0.0f );
        glVertex3f( 250 + ground_vertices[ 1 ].x, 50 + ground_vertices[ 1 ].y, 0.0f );
        glVertex3f( 250 + ground_vertices[ 2 ].x, 50 + ground_vertices[ 2 ].y, 0.0f );
        glVertex3f( 250 + ground_vertices[ 3 ].x, 50 + ground_vertices[ 3 ].y, 0.0f );

        for(int i = 0, count = bodies -> num; i < count; i++ )
        {
            body = (cpBody *)bodies -> arr[i];

            cpVect left_top = Geom :: RotateByAngle( cell_vertices[ 0 ].x, cell_vertices[ 0 ].y,  body -> a );
            cpVect left_bottom = Geom :: RotateByAngle( cell_vertices[ 3 ].x, cell_vertices[ 3 ].y, body -> a );
            cpVect right_top = Geom :: RotateByAngle( cell_vertices[ 1 ].x, cell_vertices[ 1 ].y, body -> a );
            cpVect right_bottom = Geom :: RotateByAngle( cell_vertices[ 2 ].x, cell_vertices[ 2 ].y, body -> a );

            glVertex3f( body -> p.x + left_bottom.x, body -> p.y + left_bottom.y, 0.0f );
            glVertex3f( body -> p.x + right_bottom.x, body -> p.y + right_bottom.y, 0.0f );
            glVertex3f( body -> p.x + right_top.x, body -> p.y + right_top.y, 0.0f );
            glVertex3f( body -> p.x + left_top.x, body -> p.y + left_top.y, 0.0f );

        }
    glEnd();

    glFlush();  
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void MyInit()
{
    glClearColor(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
    //glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glPointSize( 4.0 );

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, SCREEN_WIDTH, 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT, 0, 600);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(0.0f, 0.0f, 10, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);

    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);

    performance_file = fopen( "perfomance.txt", "w" );
    fclose( performance_file );
}

void ChipmunkInit()
{
    cpInitChipmunk();
    space = cpSpaceNew();
    space -> iterations = 10;
    cpSpaceResizeStaticHash( space, 30.0f, 1000 );
    cpSpaceResizeActiveHash( space, 30.0f, 1000 );
    space -> gravity = cpv( 0, -100 );
}

void NextStep( int a )
{
    times++;
    if ( times > 500 )
        exit( 0 );
    performance_file = fopen( "perfomance.txt", "a" );
    //QueryPerformanceCounter( &old_tacts );
    //QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    cpSpaceStep( space, 1.0f / 60.0f );
    //QueryPerformanceCounter( &current_tacts );
    //QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
    fprintf( performance_file, "%f\n", ( ( ( float ) current_tacts.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart ) - ( ( float )old_tacts.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart ) )  );
    sprintf( seconds_buff, "%f\n", ( ( ( float ) current_tacts.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart ) - ( ( float )old_tacts.QuadPart / freq.QuadPart ) )  );
    glutSetWindowTitle( seconds_buff );
    fclose( performance_file );
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc( 20, NextStep, 0 );
}

void KeyBoard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    if ( start )
        return;
    start = true;
    glutTimerFunc(10, NextStep, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DevilInit();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);
    glutInitWindowPosition(300, 200);   
    glutCreateWindow("Testing performance of Chipmunk");
    glutDisplayFunc( RenderScene );
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyBoard);
    MyInit();
    ChipmunkInit();
    CreateCubicks();
    CreateGround();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Описание абсолютно не ясно.

 1. Как происходит загрузка? Где код? Вполне возможно что ошибка там. (проверьте направление объекта куда происходит рендеринг)

 2. Куда рендерится текстура? Где находятся квадраты? Уместно было бы приложить скриншот сцены. (к слову вы назначаете glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); для всей сцены при перерисовке? Тогда чему удивляться?)

Comment: все поправил, остальной код в принципе не нужен

Comment: Сейчас сходу не разберусь во всех тонкостях приведенного кода, но... Очень советую пройтись пошагово по коду, и проверить насколько верно он написан) По моему сейчас закрашивание цветом находится не там где нужно, к тому же не понятно как должны перерисоваться кубики, если в RenderScene(функция рисования) нигде не светится CreateCubicks? Очень советую почитать http://pmg.org.ru/nehe/ в свое время писал по этим туториалам небольшой движек, который даже работал)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего было включено смешивание и при отрисовке картинка смешивалась с

```
glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

А это абсолютно черный цвет.

Надо ставить перед рисованием все в (1., 1., 1.). Смешивание происходит покомпонентно, следовательно если надо с текстуры вывести только зеленый канал, можно поставить цвет в (0., 1., 0.) (это на будущее может кому пригодится).

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы перевернуть картинку, поменяйте порядок вертексов: так как у вас выставлена отрисовка квадратом (GL_QUADS), то для ваших

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(256, 256);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(256, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0,   0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0,   256);
glEnd();
```

0 - 1

3 - 2

нужно указать

3 - 2

0 - 1

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0); glVertex2i(256, 0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(0,   0);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1); glVertex2i(0,   256);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1); glVertex2i(256, 256);
glEnd();
```